# How to add multi select filters to a fixed-header DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  function cbDropdown(column) {
    return $('<ul>', {
      'class': 'cb-dropdown'
    }).appendTo($('<div>', {
      'class': 'cb-dropdown-wrap'
    }).appendTo(column));
  }

  $('#example').DataTable({


    initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns().every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var ddmenu = cbDropdown($(column.header()))
          .on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
            var active;
            var vals = $(':checked', ddmenu).map(function(index, element) {
              active = true;
              return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
            }).toArray().join('|');

            column
              .search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();

            // Highlight the current item if selected.
            if (this.checked) {
              $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            } else {
              $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            }

            // Highlight the current filter if selected.
            var active2 = ddmenu.parent().is('.active');
            if (active && !active2) {
              ddmenu.parent().addClass('active');
            } else if (!active && active2) {
              ddmenu.parent().removeClass('active');
            }
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          var // wrapped
            $label = $('<label>'),
            $text = $('<span>', {
              text: d
            }),
            $cb = $('<input>', {
              type: 'checkbox',
              value: d
            });

          $text.appendTo($label);
          $cb.appendTo($label);

          ddmenu.append($('<li>').append($label));
        });
      });
    },
    paging: false,
                sort: false,
                scrollY: 500,
                scrollX: true,
                select: true,
                fixedColumns: {
                    leftColumns: 2
                },

      });
    });
```

The above is the code we are using.

The multi-select drop-down filter is working fine but when we use fix header it shrinks and the fixed header is also not working.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/41vgefnf/10/ this is the fiddle link

Comment: we are using the above jsfillde code in our application with out fixed header everything works fine..but when we use this part paging: false,
            sort: false,
            scrollY: 500,
            scrollX: true,
            select: true,
            fixedColumns: {
                leftColumns: 2
            }, the fixed header is not working and dropdown shrinks

Comment: Minor point: I recommend that you edit your question, and move the information in your comments into the body of the question (and then delete the comments).

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try  below code

```
.cb-dropdown {
position: relative;
```

hope it help apologies is suggested wrong.

here js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/0nqk1jsu/3/

Comment: but we want multi select along with fixed header